# Some packet is dropped when using TIdNotify.NotifyMethod

Tags: delphi, indy

I have a server that sends it's status every 0.1 seconds. I use this code to access UI and show the result on the client program.

```
procedure TModules.TCPServerExecute(AContext: TIdContext);
begin
   Buffer:= AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadLn();
   TIdNotify.NotifyMethod( ServerExecute );
end;
```

But some packet is not received by `ServerExecute`. I change the code and used `TIdSync.SynchronizeMethod`. The problem solved:

```
procedure TModules.TCPServerExecute(AContext: TIdContext);
begin
   Buffer:= AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadLn();
   TIdSync.SynchronizeMethod( ServerExecute );
end;
```

I have read on this site that TIdSync.SynchronizeMethod may produce deadlock.
So I want to know what is the problem with `TIdNotify.NotifyMethod`. Also I see an answer that suggest using a `Timer` to synchronize UI and don't using Notify() nor Synchronize() method.

Also I must mention that the program does rest of the work inside `ServerExecute`.

As you see I'm narrowing down the code to the following. I must mention that I executed the program with exact the following code and it already has the problem and doesn't get desired results:

```
procedure TModules.ServerExecute;
var
  I: Word;
  tmp, Packet, Cmd:string;
  CheckSum: Boolean;
begin
  //try
    frmDiag.DataLog.Lines.Add(Buffer);

    {ExplodeStr(Buffer, Cmd, Packet);

    if Cmd='status' then
    begin

      //ExplodeStr(Packet, Cmd, Packet);

      if trim(Packet)='' then
        raise Exception.Create('Empty packet received.');

      //Prepare for log
      {tmp:='';
      for I := 1 to Length(Packet) do
      begin
        if (Ord(Packet[I])>=48) and (Ord(Packet[I])<=122) then
          tmp:=tmp+Packet[I]+''
        else
          tmp:=tmp+IntToStr(Ord(Packet[I]))+'';
      end;

      //frmITCAMain.Memo1.Lines.Add(Packet);
      CheckSum:=ParsePackets(Packet);
      IntersectionsList.Int.CallNotifier;       //Call the notifier to execute assigned proc

      if frmLoader.Visible=true then
        with frmLoader do
        begin
          if
            //(Packet[1]='X') or            //Server responce
            (Packet[1]<>'l') and (Packet[1]<>'s') and (Packet[1]<>'e')and   //ignore general packet
            (
                (Req[1]<>'f')                       //Only receive ACK
                or
                ((Req[1]='f')and( (Req[2]='m')or(Req[2]='a')or(Req[2]='b') ))
                or
                (                       //Receive Data+ACK
                  (Req[1]='f')and( (Req[2]='g')or(Req[2]='h')or(Req[2]='p')or(Req[2]='j') )
                  and
                  (Packet[1]<>'k')      //Ignore ACK
                )
            )
          then
            begin
              if CheckSum then
              begin
                Res:= Packet;
                Confirm;
              end
              else
              begin
                if Packet='n' then  //Checksum failure
                  Fail
                else
                  SendPacket;   //Resend.
                //lblError.Visible:=true;
              end;
            end;
        end;

      if (Packet[1]='g') or (Packet[1]='h') or (Packet[1]='p') or
      (Packet[1]='j')  or (Packet[1]='k') then
          frmIntDetails.memReceived.Lines.Text:=tmp;

    end

    else if Cmd='server' then
    begin
      with frmLoader do
      begin
          if Visible=false then exit;

        Res:= Packet;
        if Copy(Res, 1, 2)='ok' then
            Confirm
        else
            Cancel;
      end;
    end

    else
      ClientLog.Add(Buffer);

  except on E: Exception do
    begin
      if E.Message='Connection Closed Gracefully.' then
        ClientLog.Add('X:Connection closed(Gracefully)')
      else
        ClientLog.Add(E.Message+' Buffer="'+Buffer+'"');
    end;
  end;
  //Memo2.Lines.Add( FloatToStr(TimeStampToMSecs(DateTimeToTimeStamp(Now))));
  }
end;
```

`frmDiag.DataLog` is a `TMemo` component.

Inside `frmDiag.DataLog` for example the following list is the result that i expected (The following strings is extracted from the Datalog component with `TIdSync.SynchronizeMethod` solution):

```
status:l77770000140000
status:eFFFF20000140
status:s0000
status:s0000
status:s0000
status:s0000
status:l00005555140000
status:eFFFF20000140
status:s0000
status:s0000
status:s0000
status:s0000
status:l77770000140000
status:eFFFF20000140
```

But instead I get this result:

```
status:eFFFF20000140
status:eFFFF20000140    
status:s0000
status:s0000
status:s0000
status:s0000
status:s0000
status:s0000
status:s0000
status:s0000
status:s0000
status:l00005555140000
status:l77770000140000
```

As you see **order** is not met.

I must get a `status:l77770000140000` like packet then a `status:eFFFF20000140` an then 4 `status:s0000` and so on.

@Remy I've changed your code a little:

```
TMyNotify = class(TIdNotify)
protected
  FBuffer: String;
  FMethod: TThreadMethod;
  procedure DoNotify; override;
public
  constructor Create(const ABuffer: String; AMethod: TThreadMethod);
end;

///......

{ TMyNotify }

constructor TMyNotify.Create(const ABuffer: String; AMethod: TThreadMethod);
begin
  inherited Create;
  FBuffer := ABuffer;
  FMethod := AMethod;
end;

procedure TMyNotify.DoNotify;
begin
  inherited;
  FMethod;
  //Destroy;
end;
```

And this is how I call ServerExcecute now:

```
procedure TModules.TCPServerExecute(AContext: TIdContext);
begin
  Buffer:= AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadLn();

  TMyNotify.Create(Buffer, ServerExecute).Notify;

//  ServerExecute;
//  TIdNotify.NotifyMethod( ServerExecute );
//  TIdSync.SynchronizeMethod( ServerExecute );
end;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TIdNotify` is asynchronous. If you receive a new line and overwrite your `Buffer` variable before a previous line has a chance to be processed, the previous line will be lost.  Change your code to pass the line value inside the `TIdNotify` itself, eg:

```
type
  TMyDataProc = procedure(const ABuffer: String) of object;

  TMyNotify = class(TIdNotify)
  protected
    fBuffer: String;
    fProc: TMyDataProc;
    procedure DoNotify; override;
  public
    constructor Create(const ABuffer: String; AProc: TMyDataProc);
  end;

constructor TMyNotify.Create(const ABuffer: String; AProc: TMyDataProc);
begin
  inherited Create;
  fBuffer := ABuffer;
  fProc := AProc;
end;

procedure TMyNotify.DoNotify;
begin
  fProc(fBuffer);
end;
```

```
procedure TModules.TCPServerExecute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  LBuffer: String;
begin
  LBuffer := AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadLn();
  TMyNotify.Create(LBuffer, ServerExecute).Notify();
end;

procedure TModules.ServerExecute(const ABuffer: String);
begin
  // use ABuffer as needed...
end;
```

Comment: Did not work. I also have packet-drop like problem and `TIdSync.SynchronizeMethod` solve the issue.

Comment: Then you are not processing the data correctly. I assure you, the technique I describe works perfectly fine when used correctly. I've used it many times. Ultimately, `TIdNotify` and `TIdSync` go through the same `TThread` serialization queue in the RTL, they just get there in different ways. If you are having problems with the approach I describe, then please update your question with the latest code you are actually using. Your use of `TIdSync` is not safe as you have showed it, and can still lead to data loss because you are not protecting your `Buffer` variable from concurrent access.

Comment: Thanks for your information. That is the actual `TCPServerExecute` code. The program does rest of the work inside `MyServerExecute`. Inside that function there is string parsers and after that program does some UI related work to show the results.

Comment: But you did not show any of that code yet, so there is no way to diagnose where your data loss is actually occurring.

Comment: Sorry for delay. I am not at work computer. Now as you requested I updated the question with `TCPServerExecute` code.

Comment: How is `MyServerExecute` related to `ServerExecute`? Where is `Buf` declared and how is it assigned? What TCP data is actually being transmitted? What you expect and what you log are formatted the same way but have different data, which suggests you might not be receiving what you are expecting. Either you are not showing your real code/data, or you are leaving out important details of it. Please provide a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) that demonstrates what you are really doing, and what the real problem is.

Comment: Sorry for any confusing and mistake. I've updated the question. Please kindly take a look;

Comment: You are not using the `TIdNotify` code that I gave you (and why is all the code you showed commented out?). As you have shown it, your code is not thread-safe if you have multiple clients connected, and you are doing WAY too much logic in the main thread, defeating the purpose of `TIdTCPServer`'s multi-threaded nature. You should be doing the bulk of your logic inside of `TCPSerrverExecute` itself, syncing to the main thread only when accessing the UI or other unprotected shared resources. You need to rethink how you are using `TIdTCPServer`, you are not making effective use of it.

Comment: On a side note, you might also want to consider using `TIdCmdTCPServer` instead and let its `CommandHandlers` framework to parse and break up your incoming packet data for you, instead of doing it manually.

Comment: No, I've used your code(I don't updated that part in my question). I've commented those line for simplicity(but the problem already exist. I've tested that). Remy this is **Client** program and it's not going to host multiple connection(but you right, the server program is so and I highly hunger to know what I must to do to be thread-safe in my server program). IDK why I should do most of program logic inside `TCPSerrverExecute` ? I am really confusing when you say I am not make an effective use of it.

Comment: If you are having a problem with the code I gave you, then please update your question showing how you are trying to use it. If you do not need to support multiple simultaneous connections, you might consider using `TIdSimpleServer` instead. But in any case, the bulk of your logic should be in `TCPServerExecute()` because it does not need to be delegated to the main thread, which is what `TIdSync` and `TIdNotify` do. Do as much processing in the thread that is calling `TCPServerExecute()` as you can. Delegate to the main thread only when you actually need to, such as for UI updates.

Comment: I have updated the question. Please see end of it. OK I do as you said. But may you give me more information about why my code is not thread-safe?

Comment: I explained why your code is not thread-safe. You are sharing a single `Buffer` variable across multiple threads without protecting it from concurrent access. One thread can alter the value while another thread is still waiting to use the previous value. The `TIdNotify` code I gave you eliminated that possibility, but you have altered that code to reintroduce the original problem as well as manually reproduce exactly what `TIdNotify.NotifyMethod()` does, which did not solve your original problem. You are now completely ignoring `TIdNotify.FBuffer`, which was the root of the solution.

Comment: I updated my answer with another `TIdNotify` example that more closely resembles what you are trying to accomplish with your recent edits (though you are still trying to delegate too much logic to the main thread unnecessarily).

Comment: Your code worked(Sorry for my mistakes). Your previous comment is very interesting to me(I did not know that I used a shared variable).From when I came to this site I've realize that I did not know anything about Delphi. And really appreciating for your help and time you spend for my problem.